# snmpd doesn't register a pid file on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, snmp

Package `snmpd` on Ubuntu 18.04 (installed with `apt-get`) doesn't register a pid file under `/var/run` even though `/etc/default/snmpd` reads:

```
export MIBS=
SNMPDRUN=yes
SNMPDOPTS='-Lsd -Lf /dev/null -u Debian-snmp -g Debian-snmp -I -smux,mteTrigger,mteTriggerConf -p /run/snmpd.pid'
```

By viewing the running process with `ps -axu` I see that it doesn't have the `-p` parameter defined:

```
Debian-+   393  0.1  0.1  74052 12548 ?        Ss   Jun12   8:22 /usr/sbin/snmpd -Lsd -Lf /dev/null -u Debian-snmp -g Debian-snmp -I -smux mteTrigger mteTriggerConf -f
```

On Ubuntu 16.04 the configuration is more or less the same:

```
export MIBS=
SNMPDRUN=yes
SNMPDOPTS='-Lsd -Lf /dev/null -u snmp -g snmp -I -smux,mteTrigger,mteTriggerConf -p /run/snmpd.pid'
```

And `ps -axu` does show the `-p` parameter and indeed a `/var/run/snmpd.pid` file is generated:

```
snmp      1253  0.0  0.0  66364  6856 ?        S    Jun12   4:25 /usr/sbin/snmpd -Lsd -Lf /dev/null -u snmp -g snmp -I -smux mteTrigger mteTriggerConf -p /run/snmpd.pid
```

Any idea why this is happening? I couldn't find anything specific in `/var/log/syslog` while snmpd is restarting.

Answer (score 1):

The snmpd.service file is in `/lib/systemd/system/snmpd.service`. In there, it is missing the `-p PIDFILE` parameter.

Looks like this is a known issue, fixed in a later release: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=878828

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your problem, but I am certain, that it is related to systemd. In Ubuntu 18 all services are run by systemd and configured in `/etc/systemd/system/snmpd.service`

Somewhere in this file should be a section like this:

```
...
[Service]
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/snmpd
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/snmpd $SNMPDOPTS
...
```

Maybe the variable `$SNMPDOPTS` is overwritten, changed or not used in that file.