# Unable to run SNMPD as service (18.04)

Tags: 18.04, services, snmp

It seems that [from Ubuntu 18.04 service will ignore the file `/etc/default/snmpd` file](https://askubuntu.com/a/1047565/8747).

I need to run `snmpd` with the following options (as I have them in `/etc/default/snmpd`):

```
SNMPDOPTS='-Lsd -Lf /dev/null -I -smux,mteTrigger,mteTriggerConf -p /run/snmpd.pid udp:161,udp6:161'
```

However when I run it as service, this is what is executing:

```
# service snmpd status

● snmpd.service - Simple Network Management Protocol (SNMP) Daemon.
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/snmpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2020-10-23 10:44:56 JST; 2s ago
  Process: 3089 ExecStartPre=/bin/mkdir -p /var/run/agentx (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 3091 (snmpd)
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/snmpd.service
           └─3091 /usr/sbin/snmpd -Lsd -Lf /dev/null -u Debian-snmp -g Debian-snmp -I -smux mteTrigger mteTriggerConf -f

10月 23 10:44:56 example.com systemd[1]: Starting Simple Network Management Protocol (SNMP) Daemon....
10月 23 10:44:56 example.com systemd[1]: Started Simple Network Management Protocol (SNMP) Daemon..
10月 23 10:44:58 example.com snmpd[3091]: NET-SNMP version 5.7.3
```

I have tried the solution posted [here](https://www.openpile.org/snmpd-logging-systemd.html):

> As root (or with sudo) run systemctl edit snmpd. In that new file, enter:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/snmpd -Lsd -Lf /dev/null -I -smux,mteTrigger,mteTriggerConf -p /run/snmpd.pid udp:161,udp6:161
```

However when I do that, `service snmpd status` reports:

```
● snmpd.service - Simple Network Management Protocol (SNMP) Daemon.
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/snmpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/snmpd.service.d
           └─override.conf
   Active: inactive (dead) since Fri 2020-10-23 10:51:19 JST; 4s ago
  Process: 14039 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/snmpd -Lsd -Lf /dev/null -I -smux,mteTrigger,mteTriggerConf -p /run/snmpd.pid udp:161,udp6:161 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 14038 ExecStartPre=/bin/mkdir -p /var/run/agentx (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 14039 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

10月 23 10:51:17 example.com systemd[1]: Starting Simple Network Management Protocol (SNMP) Daemon....
10月 23 10:51:17 example.com systemd[1]: Started Simple Network Management Protocol (SNMP) Daemon..
10月 23 10:51:19 example.com snmpd[14063]: NET-SNMP version 5.7.3
10月 23 10:51:19 example.com snmpd[14063]: Received TERM or STOP signal...  shutting down...
```

It seems to work for a few seconds before it exits without error.

If I stop the service and I start `snmpd` with those options manually it works fine.

What can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I solved adding `-f` at the end (which prevent the daemon from exiting):

```
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/snmpd -Lsd -Lf /dev/null -I -smux,mteTrigger,mteTriggerConf -p /run/snmpd.pid udp:161,udp6:161 -f
```